# how can i modify the contents of a file on the web using asio.boost in c++?

Tags: c++, file, boost-asio, iostream

I know how to read the contents of a file by using this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream s("www.a.com", "http");
    if(!s)
        std::cout << "Could not connect to www.a.com\n";
    s  << "GET /b.txt HTTP/1.0\r\n"
       << "Host: www.a.com\r\n"
       << "Accept: */*\r\n"
       << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n" ;
    for(std::string line; getline(s, line); )
         std::cout << line << '\n';
}
```

Is there any way to write also to a file? of course by assuming that i have the right to modify the file!

Comment: It seems like someone else also asked the same question ~15 hours ago and did not receive an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48673009/write-to-a-file-from-the-web-in-c

Comment: Yes.  Assuming you want to use HTTP for that too, you'll need to use the `PUT` verb (with a server that's configured to support it).  You'll likely need to authenticate, too.  You'll find it easier to use a HTTP library than to reinvent that wheel though.  And consider other protocols (such as FTP or SSH).

Comment: @John123 [Circumventing suspensions, quality bans, or the rate limits on posting questions / answers / comments / etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/how-should-sockpuppets-be-handled-on-stack-exchange)

Comment: @sehe my friend an I are working on a project, he asked first and didn't get any answer so i asked the question again at a different time hoping to get an answer.. have a nice day.

Comment: I answered as well as explained some of your ongoing queries in the comments. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate you posting this from your real account.

Your question is misguided.

There are no "files" on the web. There are servers, and you can speak with them.

Usual web servers speak some version of HTTP, which is nice for downloading content like HTML pages, stylesheets, images etc.

What you want to do ("write a file") is **not** a regular feature of HTTP services. However, obviously there are extensions:

- FrontPage extensions were an early thing
- WebDAV has widespread adoption (used in WebSVN, Sharepoint, supported by Apache etc.)

Pick one of the protocols and use it. Most likely you will end up with a "POST" like request (so with content-length and a body) but possibly with another HTTP "Verb" (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb498138(v=exchg.80).aspx).